# Issue with program in Scilab for calculating the cumulative distribution function of a geometric discrete random variable

Tags: probability, scilab, cumulative-sum

I wrote a program that shows the graph of cumulative distribution function and PMF of a random discrete variable with geometric distribution. But I've encountered a problem: The sum of all the probabilities of PMF is not 1, but something very close to 1.When I saw this, I switched to Matlab, where I used the function: geocdf. Thus, I observed that the first value of CDF, taking p 0.6 and n = 10, is 0.84 and not 0.6 as expected. Can you, please, help me find out what's wrong with my program ? Here's my script written in Scilab:

```
   n = input('n = '); 
tab = zeros(2, n);
p = input('p = ');//probability
q = 1 - p;

for k = 1:n   
    tab(1,k) = k;
    tab(2,k) = (q^(k - 1))*p;  
end

subplot(1,2,1);
plot(tab(1,:), tab(2,:), "-");


F = cumsum(tab(2, :));//cumulative distribution
subplot(1,2,2);
plot2d2(tab(1,:), F);

disp([tab' F']);
Mean = 1/p;
Variance = q/(p^2);

mprintf('\nMedia = %g, Dispersia = %g', Mean, Variance);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The sum of all the probabilities of PMF is not 1

You could not possibly add **all** the probabilities, because the geometric distribution assigns nonzero probabilities to all positive integers. If you run the sum up to n=10, the sum of probabilities is appreciably less than 1. If you run it up to 20, the cumulative is getting rounded to 1 in the output:

```
1.     0.6          0.6        
2.     0.24         0.84       
3.     0.096        0.936      
4.     0.0384       0.9744     
5.     0.01536      0.98976    
6.     0.006144     0.995904   
7.     0.0024576    0.9983616  
8.     0.0009830    0.9993446  
9.     0.0003932    0.9997379  
10.    0.0001573    0.9998951  
11.    0.0000629    0.9999581  
12.    0.0000252    0.9999832  
13.    0.0000101    0.9999933  
14.    0.0000040    0.9999973  
15.    0.0000016    0.9999989  
16.    0.0000006    0.9999996  
17.    0.0000003    0.9999998  
18.    0.0000001    0.9999999  
19.    4.123D-08    1.0000000  
20.    1.649D-08    1.0000000
```

> the first value of CDF, taking p 0.6 and n = 10, 0.84 and not 0.6 as expected

There are two versions of geometric distribution, as [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) explains at the very beginning of the article. Your code follows the first convention, with PMF supported on the set 1,2,3,.... Matlab's `geocdf` uses the second convention, with PMF supported on 0,1,2,3... The output of `geocdf(1,0.6)` is 0.84, representing the sum of probabilities of 0 and 1. The output of `geocdf(0,0.6)` is 0.6.